# teamcity.pullRequest.number is not identified in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, pull-request

I'm trying to trigger the build for each pull request and in that build i want to access the pull `teamcity.pullRequest.number`

`teamcity.pullRequest.number` parameter is not identified in Teamcity even after adding the pull request build feature.

I'm using the TeamCity Enterprise 2019.1.3 (build 66439).

Please suggest how to access these teamcity parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling I came to know that the parameter `teamcity.pullRequest.number` is available in 2019.2 and above versions.

As I'm using the lower version I'm unable to access it.

for more info click [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-61490)